# install socket.io on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, socket.io, real-time

I'm working on a real time application and I'm using third party to do it.
But now I have to use node.js with socket.io instead of third party .

I installed the node.js (v0.4.12) correctly and I check it using command `node -v` .
but when I was installed the socket.io using `npm install socket.io` command I got this error .

```
npm ERR! install failed Error: Required package: options(latest) not found. (Found: ["0.0.3"])
npm ERR! install failed (required by: ws@0.4.23)
npm ERR! install failed     at /usr/share/npm/lib/build.js:192:19
npm ERR! install failed     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/graceful-fs.js:32:9)
npm ERR! Error: Required package: options(latest) not found. (Found: ["0.0.3"])
npm ERR! (required by: ws@0.4.23)
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/build.js:192:19
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/graceful-fs.js:32:9)
npm ERR! Report this *entire* log at <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! Just tweeting a tiny part of the error will not be helpful.
npm not ok
```

How I can solve it?

Comment: Node 0.4 is badly out of date.  Install the current version first.

Comment: Thank you .
I solved it using These commands :
1- sudo npm install -g n
2-sudo n 0.8.15
3-sudo npm install socket.io

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I ran those commands and it worked:

1. `sudo npm install -g n`
2. `sudo n 0.8.15`
3. `sudo npm install socket.io`

Comment: I get this - Error: invalid version 0.8.15

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to install it without a [package.json](http://package.json.jit.su/) file, and in your solution you installed it globally, which is usually not what you want for socket.io.

Instead, you should include a **package.json** file in your working directory and either run:

```
> npm install socket.io --save
```

which will automatically append it to **package.json**, or your you can physically include it in the dependencies and then just run:

```
> npm install
```

Answer (score 3):

It worked:

1) sudo npm install -g n 
2) sudo n 0.8.15 
3) sudo npm install socket.io

Answer (score 1):

In some cases if you are behind a proxy and try to run:

**sudo npm install socket.io**

you may end up in getting error -

npm ERR! Error: shasum check failed for /tmp/npm-1393245157089/1393245157089-0.6057841922156513/tmp.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: 3bab0444e49b55fbbc157424dbd41aa375a51a76
npm ERR! Actual:   dae95023b71f7d06533f7c35a7d0c3b0cf729f42

then run the following

**sudo npm --proxy=http://"your_proxy":"your_port" install socket.io**